# a way to use an arbitary stack

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I'm new for ROS.
I have a question about how to use and implement a stack.

I've already read all of the tutorials of ROS.
But I couldn't find the way to implement an arbitrary stack.

For instance, I'd like to use an OpenCV with ROS.(My PC has NOT been installed OpenCV)
In this case, first I install ROS(electric).
Second, I get the stack, vision_opencv via internet.
Next, what should I do?

Sorry for my beginner's question.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31004/a-way-to-use-an-arbitary-stack/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a vital, but subtle, distinction between a *package* and a *stack*. It goes like this: a stack is an installation-level construct, while a package is a user-level construct.

That is: a package never "uses" a stack: it only uses other packages. Groups of packages that "belong together" are *distributed* as stacks.

To have one package use another, you add the appropriate `<depend>` tag to your `manifest.xml`; you can then `#include` headers provided by the package you're using, link against libraries, and so on.

For the specific example of OpenCV, you want to add

`<depend package="opencv2"/>`

to your package's `manifest.xml`, and then you can use OpenCV just as if you'd installed the library and dealt with the various compile flags yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1